# Fresh install of PostgreSQL 15.3-3 on Windows 11 with pgAdmin 4 v7.4 wont start - Stuck at "Loading pgAdmin 4 v7.4..."

Tags: postgresql

I have installed a fresh PostgreSQL on Windows 11.
I get this when I try to start pgAdmin:

> Loading pgAdmin 4 v7.4...

It never gets pass this.

I tried to add "Content Type=text/javascript" and "ContentType=text/javascript" to Regedit > HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.js. That did not solve the issue.

[image]

Please advice what I should try to get pgAdmin running.

Comment: Use a different client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Downloading the previous installer for PostgreSQL 15.3-2 solves the issue, the old installer is available here:
https://get.enterprisedb.com/postgresql/postgresql-15.3-2-windows-x64.exe

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue...

I was updating PostgreSQL on 3 machines, and on the first one I installed PostgreSQL 15.3-**2**
and there are no issues, and on other 2 machines I have installed PostgreSQL 15.3-**3** and have the same problem, it is stuck on loading. I believe that this is then PostgreSQL's problem that they need to solve. I think this version 15.3-3 was just released.